# how can i rewrite a special URL?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to rewrite the following URL:

https://exampledomain.com/wp/anmelden to

https://exampledomain/anmelden

I have tried several solutions which I found in other posts on Stack Overflow. But no solution worked for me. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www\.exampledomain\.com
RewriteRule ^wp/anmelden$ /anmelden
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're simply trying to remove the `/wp/` directory from the URL then you can use the following rule in your `.htaccess`:

```
<if "%{HTTP_HOST} == 'exampledomain.com/wp/anmelden'">
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^(.*)wp/ /$1 [L,R=301]
</if>
```

This will leave you with the URL: `https://exampledomain/anmelden`. Make sure you clear your cache before testing this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When i use your code i have problems with css-files. I only wan to rewrite this one URL (http://exampledomain/wp/anmelden). The other urls should not be rewrited.

Comment: Ah I see, I've included an if statement so that that rule will only run IF the URL is `exampledomain.com/wp/anmelden`. Alternatively you can also use a Rewrite Condition.

Comment: thanks! But if i use the code with the if statement i get a 500 Server-error... any ideas?

Comment: you have another idea? Your code causes a 500 server error